# Can I use the AccessibleObjectFromWindow() function to retrieve the address of the interface for the Outlook window object?

Tags: c++, outlook, ms-word, outlook-addin, add-in

I am trying to resolve one bug with [`AccessibleObjectFromWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-accessibleobjectfromwindow).

I am unable to retrieve `ppvObject` for Outlook, whereas it works well for MSWord.

```
WindowPtr pdocWdw;
HRESULT var = AccessibleObjectFromWindow( hControlWnd, DWORD(OBJID_NATIVEOM),
        __uuidof(WindowPtr), (PVOID*)&pdocWdw );
    
_DocumentPtr pDoc;

if(pdocWdw != NULL)
{
    m_pdocWdw = pdocWdw;
    pDoc = pdocWdw->Document;
}
```

For Word, `pDoc = pdocWdw->Document;` returns the proper value, but in case of Outlook it throws an exception.

Can anybody please tell if I can use `AccessibleObjectFromWindow()` for Outlook? If not, what alternative can I use?

Comment: How do you retreive hControlWnd?

Comment: Do you develop an Outlook add-in or just automate it?